# xcode 4 and svn

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, xcode4

i develop in xcode4 and we have an svn server, i connect to the repository an i see all the commit done by other programmers. my question is how i can import the entire project localy to my machine to develop ? i would like to import the project to begin developement but not commit, i would like to test and after commit.

thanks for your answers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click on the repository that you want to check out and then click on `Check Out` button on top of the window.

I also learned that today.

Comment: hi, when i Check out, there are files ( new files committed by other programmers) witch not appear in my new project ( the project witch a check out), i mean that for example when an other developer add a new class and when i check out, this class did't appear in my new project. what is the problem ?

Comment: well there are 2 reasons for that 1. That he did not commit it. 2. he did not commit his pbx..... file . check the scm section in groups and folder . if there are any files listed in scm then you can not see those changes when you check out.